# VB.NET AmbiguousMatchException with my Array loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, listview, multidimensional-array, ambiguous

Whenever I try and use this loop it crashes and displays an AmbiguousMatchException, but when I change it to Do Until k = 2, The code runs without a problem.

```
Do Until k = 4
    i(k) = listview1.Items.Add(p(k, 0))
    With i(k)
        .SubItems.Add(p(k, 1))
        .SubItems.Add(p(k, 2))
        .SubItems.Add(p(k, 3))
        .SubItems.Add(p(k, 4))
    End With
    k = k + 1
Loop
```

I'm very new to VB.NET coding but can someone try to explain the problem here

Comment: I have something telling me this `is not all the code`...

Comment: I can add the rest if that would help

Comment: Yes, that would be nice. Right now I do not know what `i` is (defined as) or `p`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I suspect is your have a value in p that is not a string or even more is = Nothing.

Example:

```
Public Sub Bad()

    Dim listview1 As ListView = New ListView
    Dim t = Nothing
    Dim k As Integer = 0
    'Not Declared with a Type
    Dim p(,) = {{"string", "string", "string", "string", "string"}, _
                        {"string", "string", "string", "string", "string"}, _
                        {"string", "string", "string", "string", t}, _
                        {"10", "10", "test", "10", t}, _
                        {"10", "10", "test", "10", t}} 'Notice I added t as a value
    Dim i(4) As ListViewItem

    Do Until k = 4
        i(k) = listview1.Items.Add(p(k, 0))
        With i(k)
            .SubItems.Add(p(k, 1))
            .SubItems.Add(p(k, 2))
            .SubItems.Add(p(k, 3))
            .SubItems.Add(p(k, 4))
        End With
        k = k + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Public Sub Good()

    Dim listview1 As ListView = New ListView
    Dim t As String = Nothing
    Dim k As Integer = 0
    'Declared as String
    Dim p(,) As String = {{"string", "string", "string", "string", "string"}, _
                        {"string", "string", "string", "string", "string"}, _
                        {"string", "string", "string", "string", t}, _
                        {"10", "10", "test", "10", t}, _
                        {"10", "10", "test", "10", t}} 'Notice I added t as a value

    Dim i(4) As ListViewItem

    Do Until k = 4
        i(k) = listview1.Items.Add(p(k, 0))
        With i(k)
            .SubItems.Add(p(k, 1))
            .SubItems.Add(p(k, 2))
            .SubItems.Add(p(k, 3))
            .SubItems.Add(p(k, 4))
        End With
        k = k + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

The only difference between the 2 Methods is P is declared as String and the other is not.  When you add a value that has not been cast ToString Reflection makes it's best guess as to the type of the value.  If reflection cannot figure out what type of value is being past because it matches more than 1 type the AmbiguousMatchException is thrown.

So in this case the value of t = Nothing Nothing can equal a type of pretty well anything.  As you can see from the code below.

```
    Dim r = CType(Nothing, String)
    r = CType(Nothing, Integer)
    r = CType(Nothing, Object)
    r = CType(Nothing, Integer)
```

To help avoid this situation it is best to add on the first line:

```
Option Strict On
```

It will disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing